# Word for Mac on NFS share thinks documents are read only

Tags: mac, network, ms-office, smb, nfs

I have a strange issue with am Unraid server running NFS shares.

Facts:

- Running a fresh install of Word on a fresh Mac on a fresh Unraid server
- Documents are on an NFS4 network share
- The share and documents has all permissions: Read - Write - Execute
- I can verify this by using "Get info" on a Word document and see that myself, mygroup and all users have Read and Write. I can also verify directly on server. Documents are 777 (rwx for all)
- Ready only is not set on document (as seen from Mac get info)
- Locked is not set on document (as seen from Mac get info)

Symptoms:

- When I open a document located on the share in Word on the Mac - it displays a message that the document is read only and only gives me the option do duplicate it. I can duplicate it fine and save to the network location, but when opening the duplicated document, I get the read only message again.
- No other programs are behaving this way on the same share - Excel, Powerpoint etc works fine. I can even open a Word document in a text editor and are able to save it - so if it definitely not read only
- If I create a new Word document and save it to this network share - I get the same behaviour - it gets read only
- If I map the network share using samba (SMB) protocol instead of NFS, it works fine - issue is only with NFS (but I prefer NFS due to speed & reliability when there are many files)

So somehow Word thinks that documents on the network share are read only - while they definitely not are read only.

Any ideas?

Comment: The issue is your NFS share permissions and/or how it’s been mounted. Word and macOS are not relevant here (up to the point of your mount command or fstab entry).  How are you mounting the NFS share?

Comment: @Allan Mounting is fine. Mounted as RW and this also shows. Found that the issue is related to NFS v4. NFS v4 has new locking behaviour and probably this is the reason. Will rever to v3 for now.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the issue is using NFS version 4. Using NFS version 3 resolves the issue. In version 4 the locking behaviour is different, and this is probably the reason. I will be using NFS v. 3 for now.